# Is There Any tool or way to get customer tracking url/path in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to track a path of customer from page to page, or Track There Travel Activity.

for ex: initially customer is on homepage, then went to product listing and then product details page and so on...

So I want customer or any relative info and then Homepage URL, Product listing URL, Product Details URL ...

And Simply we can say trace customer activity on Website.

**Is there any tool or any way to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

You can copy vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html to your theme and edit line 56 (here you can change block for which display track information), you can change it like this

```
{{
    block class='Your_Package\\Your_Module\\Block\\Sales\\Email\\Shipment\\Track' 
    area='frontend' 
    template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' 
    shipment=$shipment order=$order
}}
```

After that you need create this block

```
<?php

namespace Your_Package\Your_Module\Block\Sales\Email\Shipment;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Track extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Order\TrackFactory
     */
    protected $_trackFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Order\TrackFactory $trackFactory
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Order\TrackFactory $trackFactory,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_trackFactory = $trackFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve tracking by tracking entity id
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTrackingInfoByTrackId($trackId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Order\Track $track */
        $track = $this->_trackFactory->create()->load($trackId);
        if ($track->getEntityId()) {
            $result = $track->getNumberDetail();
        } else {
            $result = null;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then copy template vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml to your theme and change line 25 to

```
<td>
    <?php 
        $trackingInfo = $block->getTrackingInfoByTrackId($_item->getEntityId());
    ?>
    <?php if ($trackingInfo->getUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeHtml($trackingInfo->getUrl()) ?>"
           onclick="this.target='_blank'">
            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

You also may need copy vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new_guest.html the same like shipment_new.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics can be used to a point

Although I think you need to look at  Google enhanced ecommerce tracking

In which case you need to look at something like this

https://marketplace.magento.com/tatvic-actionablegoogleanalytics.html?source=pepperjam&publisherId=167159&clickId=2829786002

You want the user tracking

Although if you search enhanced ecommerce tracking there are plenty of extensions if this one doesn't meet your need